# Cannot assign to read only property 'RGBA8' of object '#<WebGLRenderingContext>'

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

After I upgraded my Chrome browser to version 122.0.6261.70 (Official Build) (64-bit) today, my WebGL program stopped working and threw an exception `Cannot assign to read only property 'RGBA8' of object '#'`. Does anyone know the reason for this?

about code:

```
if (!gl.isWebGL2) {
    gl.RGBA8 = gl.RGBA;
    gl.RGB8 = gl.RGB;
}
```

An exception was thrown when executing `gl.RGBA8 = gl.RGBA;`.

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wv7h.png)

When I rolled back the browser or removed the relevant code, everything went back to normal.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)?